# Inconsistent results from lookupTransform in tf

Tags: ros, rviz, tf

I'm performing AprilTag detection. I've calibrated my camera for the 'camera_link.' I want to obtain the world position of the detected tag (in this case, 'tag_0') using the following code. When I run the code, I expect occasional errors, which I can accept. However, in about 1 out of 5 runs, I get a different result from what I see in RViz. The result I see in RViz is correct, but the result I obtain from the code is incorrect. Why am I getting different results from RViz in some of my runs?

I perform my tests with the tag and camera fixed. Expected values :
[image: asd]

result for some times:

```
([ 0.9111280553731542, -0.3449667317718065, 0.3432170894107306],
 [-0.0222108766410733,  0.1517188960143932, 0.9879820550257965, -0.019481028035649134])
```

From what I've noticed, it seems like the quaternion part is the negation of the same value.

correct result some times:

```
([0.9248629165692426, -0.3518433209173788,  0.275606008083854],
 [0.0190496614165582, -0.1624377427170215, -0.9862928801197453, 0.021861115303710876])
```

Below is the tf tree :
[image]

my code :

```
import tf
import rospy
import logging


class WorldPoseCalculator():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node("CleanX")

        self.__position_listener = tf.TransformListener()

    def get_world_position(self, link: str = "/tag_0") -> tuple:

        self.__position_listener.waitForTransform(
            '/world', '/tag_0', rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(4.0))
        (trans, rot) = self.__position_listener.lookupTransform(
            "world", '/tag_0', rospy.Time(0))  # self.tfBuffer.lookup_transform("world",link,time)

        return (trans, rot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    zzz = WorldPoseCalculator()
    print(zzz.get_world_position())
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The screenshot (RViz) shows camera_color_optical_frame, which is not used in your Python code. Furthermore, the z-coordinates of the two poses you shared are very different. Please check!

Comment: Hi @ravi Yes, actually, I'm also trying to understand why, when I run the same code, the z value is sometimes calculated correctly and sometimes incorrectly. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: You are using "/tag_0" in Python and showing us "camera_color_optical_frame" frame in RViz. The RViz screenshot does not have global frame mentioned. Therefore, RViz screenshot is not useful. Also, Please remove "/" from these frame id in your Python code.

Answer (score 1):

In quaternion space, the same rotation is represented by 2 values: q and -q (where -q means negating each term of q.) There is a more mathematical analysis [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016282/negative-quaternion).

So whatever bug you have, the -q is not the problem.

Update: just to clarify, the good/bad examples you show are NOT q and -q. They represent two different rotations.

Comment: I don't fully understand the reason, but the C++ version of the Python code above works without any issues